# Laravel 5 Built in Auth - Register with profile picture

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.3

I want to make registration form which has profile picture. I want to save the image to asset folder and image path to DB. Can someone explain how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This guy has a great step by step tutorial on building a social network and it has a section where he adds the avatar in the registration step (although its just a default image, you can adapt it) [Add Registration Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXtgFR0OdxU&list=PLZAiN3wmUtzV1eI7mAxERQaE2LkyA5Nh6&index=1). There is another video later in his series which show how to edit this image [Updating user Profile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sdj9lvihyWY&list=PLZAiN3wmUtzV1eI7mAxERQaE2LkyA5Nh6&index=6)

I hope this helps.